# chrono with different time periods?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Currently I am using `boost::rational<std::uint64>` to keep track in my application.

Basically I have a clock that runs over a very long period of time and will be tick by different components of different time resolutions, e.g. 1/50s, 1/30s, 1001/30000s etc... I want to maintain perfect precision, i.e. no floating point. `boost::rational` works well for this purpose, however I think it would be better design to use `std::chrono::duration` for this.

My problem though is, how can I use `std::chrono::duration` here? Since it uses a compile time period I don't quite see how I can use it in my scenario where I need to maintain precision?

Comment: Time accuracy is mostly operating system and hardware dependent. On many Linux systems it could be not better than 10 milliseconds.

Comment: What is your problem with `chrono::duration`? Doesn't your clock work on discrete time chunks?

Comment: @Grizzly: No I'm using different clocks of different accuracy to keep track of time.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I am not using only "regular" OS clocks, sometimes I am connected to a clock which is much more accurate than what is usually available in a computer, in discrete time steps over long periods of time.

Comment: @ronag: Wouldn't that still give you discrete timings depending on the precision of the clock (which I suppose to be finite)?

Comment: @Grizzly: Yes, but since there are different clocks with different discrete timings I would loose precision, e.g. how would you make 1/50 and 1001/30000 work together, without loosing precision?

Comment: I would `typedef` durations beyond `nano`, `milli`, etc for your 1001/30000 case and just use `duration_cast` between my representations.

Comment: `1/50` would be `600/30000`, so I don't see the problem with making it work together. For other fractions you might need to take a higher denominator (and if it gets to crazy look for a library supporting integers `>64bit`), but in theory I don't really see a problem

Comment: @Grizzly: That works given that I can figure out the right denominator in advance...

Comment: @ronag If you know all the potential periods then you can get an appropriate duration by using one with a period that is the GCD of the known periods. `std::common_type` on durations will do the calculation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allowed to set the period to `1` and use a floating point type for `Rep`.

I *suspect* that you can do the same thing with `boost::rational`, but you'll have to look quite closely at `std::chrono`, which I haven't done. Look at `treat_as_floating_point` and `duration_values`. Also try to figure out what the standard means by "An arithmetic type or a class emulating an arithmetic type".

One might reasonably argue that if `boost::rational` doesn't emulate an arithmetic type, then it's not doing its job. But it doesn't *necessarily* follow that it really does everything `std::chrono::duration` expects.

Comment: So, I guess what you are saying is that it might work with `boost::rational`?

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding your question, and **if** you know all of the different time resolutions at compile-time, then the following will do what you want.  You can figure out the correct tick period by using `common_type` on all of your different time resolutions as shown below:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>

struct clock
{
    typedef std::uint64_t                      rep;
    typedef std::common_type
    <
        std::chrono::duration<rep, std::ratio<1, 50>>,
        std::chrono::duration<rep, std::ratio<1, 30>>,
        std::chrono::duration<rep, std::ratio<1001, 30000>>
    >::type                                    duration;
    typedef duration::period                   period;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<clock>     time_point;
    static const bool is_steady =              true;

    static time_point now()
    {
        // just as an example
        using namespace std::chrono;
        return time_point(duration_cast<duration>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()));
    }
};
```

This will compute at compile-time the largest tick period which will exactly represent each of your specified resolutions.  For example with this clock one can exactly represent:

- 1/50 with 600 ticks.
- 1/30 with 1000 ticks.
- 1001/30000 with 1001 ticks.

The code below exercises this `clock` and uses the "chrono_io" facility described [here](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/bloomington/chrono_io.html) to print out not only the run-time number of ticks of your clock, but also the compile-time units of your clock-tick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "chrono_io"

int main()
{
    auto t0 = clock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    auto t1 = clock::now();
    std::cout << (t1-t0) << '\n';
}
```

For me this prints out:

```
633 [1/30000]seconds
```

Meaning:  There were 633 clock ticks between calls to `now()` and the unit of each tick is 1/30000 of a second.  If you don't want to be beholden to "chrono_io" you can inspect the units of your clock with `clock::period::num` and `clock::period::den`.

If your different time resolutions are not compile-time information, then your current solution with `boost::rational` is probably best.